# How to map User,Department,Role in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am using hibernate 4 in my web application. I have Person, Department & Role. As by the name one person can have more than role, as well as more than one department. But each role is specific to particular department. I designed like below.

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JoinTable(name = "person_department_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Department, Role> roleByDepartment = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

As per the above setup I can't add more than one department to any person. What change needs to be done on this code, so that one person can have more than one role as well as more than one department? Any advice.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, were you able to fix it? Did the below answer was helpful or were you able to find a solution by yourself. If you found the solution, can you share it here as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly specify `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relationships.

In addition, if you would like to have a `Person` retrieved with its `Departments` and `Roles` and vice versa, you need to specify Jackson `@JsonManagedReference` and `@jsonBackReference` annotations as well.

Please review the following examples below and post here again if you still encounter issues.

**OneToMany/ManyToOne:** http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/

**JsonManagedReference/JsonBackReference:** http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion